# Why does Guillotine have of 45 degreed blade rather than the one parallel to the ground?

Tags: classical-mechanics

What is the point of having 45 degreed blade in Guillotine? After all, the pressure-Force over Area-blade imposes to the neck is the same either way.

Comment: Now this is a question that can safely be said to belong at meatpacking.se. -1

Comment: @space_cadet Do you mean that you think this is not a physics question, or that you are uncomfortable with its macabre subject matter?

Comment: The former. I'm just trying to redeem my reputation as an enabler of ridiculous questions.

Comment: @space_cadet: for what it's worth, you certainly don't have that reputation in my view ;-)

Comment: Frankly, I'm curious about the answer, although not so much I'd be interested to do much work looking for it myself.

Comment: @space_cadet: I believe you should vote to close or flag for moderation attention if you think the question doesn't belong here. Votes are reserved for potentially good questions that need better formulation. At least that's what I think, anyway :-)

Comment: @marek - will do.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: I am curious too. About as much as about what I'll have for lunch today. But I'll ask neither of these questions here :-)

Comment: @Marek, why wouldn't you ask such questions here?

Comment: @Comptrol: because I don't think it's physics. You can certainly devise a killing machine with about any kind of blade you could imagine. Why one certain killing machine has one certain kind of blade is question about history and engineering, not physics.

Comment: great, so pressure of solid objects aren't related to the physics.

Comment: @Comptrol: At the moment, this is indeed more of a history/engineering question. If you care to rephrase it as a more of a physics problem, I don't mind reopening it.

Comment: @Comptrol: Try cutting potato when you hold knife horizontal its bit difficult but when you hold it slanted it is somewhat easier. What I am thinking is it would require heavier blade if the blade is parallel to the ground. I guess smaller part of blade touches the neck providing more pressure. If you rephrase it I will vote to reopen it. (also google `reason for slanted blade of guillotine`)

Comment: Why closed? I think there is a physics related answer to this. It has to do with the contact mechanics, and the strength of materials.

Comment: If anything, the cutting of the person's neck is a task spread over a longer length of cutting edge than if the blade were at 90° to the direction of travel. The blade stays sharper longer. You get more necks per sharpening. It is a simple efficiency calculation but I just don't have a head for that stuff.

Comment: To the folk, I found the answer thanks to @ssg. With 45 degree, blade can move downwards fast. and along with the sharpness and weight of the blade, this movement results in separation of the head from the body. And why the 45 degree but not another one? I think, if the angle was larger, that might not contribute enough weight and pressure. and if it was smaller, the blade might not move downwards just as fast and cutting wouldn't occur.

Comment: Just stumbled on this.  It's actually a good question, too bad they shut it down.  I don't think the answer has to do with the pressure force distribution or anything, but rather with the transverse motion of the blade at the contact point.  My guess is the transverse motion inhibits microscopic binding between the blade and matter being cut.

Comment: Not having read all the comments, I would guess it is because it creates a sawing motion rather than a chopping one, which—if you have even cut meat you will know—goes through much easier.

Comment: I sort of agree with hellogoodbye. I think the steeper the angle would be the better.