# Warning: Gruesome. Which one cuts faster? Guillotine with a slanted blade or with a flat blade?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure

The following image shows Guillotine that is a device designed for carrying out executions by decapitation.

[image]

Intuitively, slicing with pushing is less effective than slicing with pushing and sliding. When slicing, the contact area varies, which in turns make the pressure varies even though the force is kept unchanged.

Shortly speaking, what is the effect of slanted blade? Does it cut faster?

Bonus question: Is slicing with pushing is less effective than slicing with pushing and sliding? What makes the difference?

Comment: Dear PGFTricks - I added a warning to your title: otherwise it's not altogether clear that your question is about the beheading machine and some people could find this upsetting (on a physics site one might expect the industrial shearing process known as guillotining).

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: No problem. It is just for an example. But the context is still in physics. I love physics  not killing. :-)

Comment: To tell the truth I have been curious about this because the industrial machines have the same slanted blade: I suspect in the industrial machine that the blade is actuated from the thin end, therefore, through moment balance, there is extremely high pressure on the initially small contact region, which begins the cut in the target material (especially sheet metal) which then propagates like a crack. This would be even more pronounced in a brittle material like wood.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2289/17609

Comment: Because slicing is easier than chopping?

Comment: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." <== Which answer do you mean? No answer, baby!